# On a RSA environment, which schema to use to encrypt the message

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I understand the use of the private and public keys in a RSA environment but what schema must be used to encrypt the message?
Must there be an agreement between the users of each key to use the same schema?
By schema I mean AES... DES...SHA...ARC4.
If I am not using the proper terminology my apologies...

Comment: Are you talking about using a RSA key pair to encrypt/decrypt a symmetric key?  Then yes, both parties need to agree on a format, what symmetric  algorithm is being used and possibly an IV/padding scheme as well.

Comment: Incidentally SHA does not belong in that list, its a hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If by "schema" you mean using a symmetric algorithm to encrypt the data then yes, they must agree on which one to use.

This is actually the way to go: asymmetric crypto (in this scenario, RSA) is really slow compared to symmetric algorithms (AES, DES...), so if A wants to send a large message to B, then they perform the following steps:

- Generate a random key K to be used for the symmetric algorithm.
- Encrypt the  data using the symmetric algorithm and the key K
- Encrypt K using B's public RSA key.
- Send both the encrypted message (symmetric) and the encrypted key (asymmetric)

B decodes the message like this:

- Un-encrypt the key K using their RSA private key
- Un-encrypt the message using K.

Obviously, A and B must have an agreement on which symmetric algorithm to use.